# Joomla, change the order of the listed articles

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla site [murthysuresh.com](http://www.murthysuresh.com).  I added a new article today but it appears on the right bottom of the page. There are only 3 articles and I want them sorted by published date. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you know there is a special stackexchange site just for joomla: [joomla.se] which would be the best place to ask this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

In Admin Panel >> Content >> Articles on the right side from the dropdown select : "Date descending"